# Matlab crash after returning from function that calls MEX

Tags: c++, matlab, memory-management, crash, mex

I'm creating a MEX to find a path between two nodes using the A* algorithm. The code works as expected, retrieves the right result and everything seems to be fine, but when I return from the method that calls the MEX, Matlab simply shuts itself down.

As I know sometimes Matlab creates a pointer to the same memory address when the user tries to create a copy of a variable (I.E. A = 3; B = A, then A and B are pointing to the same memory address, even though Matlab shows them as 2 independent variables) I used an old trick that consists on performing an operation directly to the copy of the variable, even if its a silly one, Matlab will think that the two variables are no longer the same and will create a copy of it (I.E. A = 3; B = A; B = B+0, now A and B are stored as different and independent variables).

So the only way that I have found to fix the issue is to do what is shown below in function getWP:

```
function testAStarC()
    % load the map of the area
    load('epsp0_2_nav.mat');

    % Set the initial node
    initNode = '16x21';
    % Set the target node
    finalNode = '-15x54';

    % Select Heuristic
    heuristic = 'Manhattan';

    % Create a target location (targetX, targetY, targetAngle)
    targetCoords = [-15*110  54*110 0.15];

    % Function that hosts the call to the MEX
    wp = getWP(map, initNode, finalNode, targetCoords, heuristic);

    disp('If you remove the line cellNodes{keyID}.x = cellNodes{keyID}.x; from getWP ...
        I wont reach this line');
    disp(['Route with ',num2str(length(wp)),' wp found']);
    disp('done');


function waypointsList = getWP(map, initNode, finalNode, targetCoords, heuristic)
    % HashMap containing the nodes (this is a Java hashmap)
    nodesHash = map.navMap.nodes.nodes;
    keys = nodesHash.keys();
    numNodes = length(keys);

    cellNodes = cell(1,numNodes);

    % Parse the nodes from the HashMap to Cells as the MEX seems to be
    % unable to read directly from the Java HashMap
    for keyID=1:numNodes
        cellNodes{keyID} = nodesHash(keys{keyID});

        %---------------------------------------------------------
        % WITHOUTH THIS MATLAB CRASHES WHEN RETURNING FROM GETWP
        %---------------------------------------------------------
        % We need this to force Matlab to create a new copy of the content,
        % otherwise will send a pointer aiming to the HashMap and crash when
        % returning from getWP.
        cellNodes{keyID}.x = cellNodes{keyID}.x;
    end

    waypointsList = AStar(cellNodes, initNode, finalNode, targetCoords, heuristic, 1);
    disp('I am not crashing here if you remove cellNodes{keyID}.x = cellNodes{keyID}.x');
```

My first thought was that I was doing something wrong to "cellNodes" inside the MEX and this was causing Matlab to crash, but I am not performing any operations using directly the input parameter. This is the constructor for the Node class:

Node.cpp

```
Node::Node(mxArray *cellElement)
{
    double *xIn;
    double *yIn;
    char strIn[15];
    double *posXIn;
    double *posYIn;
    double *weightIn;
    double *tempVal;

    size_t numCellElms;
    mxArray *cellElement2;
    numCellElms = mxGetNumberOfFields(cellElement);
    size_t size;

    for (int cellItem = 0; cellItem < numCellElms; cellItem++)
    {
        cellElement2 = mxGetCell(cellElement,cellItem);
        if (cellItem == 0)
        {
            xIn = mxGetPr(cellElement2);
            memcpy(tempVal,xIn,sizeof(double));
            gridX = int(*tempVal);
        }

        if (cellItem == 1)
        {
            yIn = mxGetPr(cellElement2);
            memcpy(tempVal,yIn,sizeof(double));
            gridY = int(*tempVal);
        }
    
        if (cellItem >= 2 && cellItem < 10)
        {
            mwSize buflen = mxGetN(cellElement2)*sizeof(mxChar)+1;
            if (buflen <= 1)
            {
                connections[cellItem-2][0] = '\0';
            }
            else
            {
                mxGetString(cellElement2, strIn, buflen);
                memcpy(&connections[cellItem-2][0], strIn, buflen);              
            }
        }
    
        if (cellItem == 10)
        {
            posXIn = mxGetPr(cellElement2);
            memcpy(&posX,posXIn,sizeof(double));            
        }                
        if (cellItem == 11)
        {
            posYIn = mxGetPr(cellElement2);
            memcpy(&posY,posYIn,sizeof(double));  
        }        
        if (cellItem == 12)
        {
            posXIn = mxGetPr(cellElement2);
            memcpy(&wpX,posXIn,sizeof(double));            
        }                
        if (cellItem == 13)
        {
            posYIn = mxGetPr(cellElement2);
            memcpy(&wpY,posYIn,sizeof(double));  
        }                
        if (cellItem == 14)
        {
            weightIn = mxGetPr(cellElement2);
            memcpy(&weight,weightIn,sizeof(double));              
        }                                
    }

    sprintf(xStr,"%i",gridX);
    sprintf(yStr,"%i",gridY);
    sprintf(key,"%ix%i",gridX,gridY);
}
```

And this is how I initialize the Nodes list inside the AStar.cpp

```
// Create nodes in the nodes hash
mxArray *cellElement;
std::map<std::string, Node> nodesHash;
for (int nodeID=0; nodeID < numberOfNodes; nodeID++) 
{
    cellElement = mxGetCell(prhs[0], nodeID);
    Node n(cellElement);
    nodesHash[n.key] = n;
}
```

Form now on nothing uses prhs[0] anymore, as nothing has altered the content of the prhs[0] (variable containing the pointer to the Matlab variable cellNodes), this variable should be exactly the same after leaving the MEX.

From here I have two questions:

1. If nothing is altering the content of the first parameter, why should it crash when returning from getWP?
2. Is there a more elegant way of forcing Matlab to create a real copy of a variable?

Thanks!

*Edit1: Using Matlab 2015b in Windows10 64 bit.

Comment: You don’t need to create a copy of your variable. Your MEX-file should simply not write into its input. This is explicitly forbidden by the API. Just don’t do it. Use `mxDuplicateArray` inside your MEX-function to copy the input to the output, then modify the output. Or simply create a new output array. Make your MEX-file work with simple data so it’s cheaper to copy.

Comment: Wait, discard that. It looks like your C++ code is memcpy-ing into unallocated memory?

Comment: Writing into prhs[ ] variables will not crash MATLAB. What it *will* potentially do is create unwanted side effects of altering multiple variables, possibly even literal variable such as 1:3 that MATLAB keeps off to the side. I do agree with Chris that tempVal is an uninitialized pointer that you are using for memcpy( ) and dereferencing.  Since this is apparently being used for a scalar double, a simple fix is to define tempVar as an array of size 1. I.e., double tempVar[1];  You should check all of the pointers being used in your routines to make sure they are assigned or allocated.

Comment: MATLAB does not publish their rules for variable sharing, so there is no *official* method for unsharing them.  It can be impossible to detect this even with hacking into the mxArray in a mex routine.  The best you can do is try your assignment trick. E.g., A(1) = A(1).  Modifying prhs[ ] variables inplace in a mex routine is of course discouraged and against the rules, but when working with very large variables sometimes it may be necessary because of resource constraints.

Comment: If you are just copying scalar doubles from mxArray variables, maybe consider using mxGetScalar( ) instead of doing all that pointer and memcpy stuff.

Comment: Thanks CrisLuengo and JamesTursa ! Your answers are spot on! 

If any of you can post it as an answer I will mark it as "solved".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### SOVED by @CrisLuengo and @JamesTursa.

**1) If nothing is altering the content of the first parameter, why should it crash when returning from getWP?**

[Node.cpp] 'double* tempVal' was not allocated, although the code worked, this was possibly messing with the integrity of prhs[0] thus causing Matlab to crash when returning from the function that invoked the MEX.

The solution was to declare tempVal as 'double tempVal[1]'.
After that, the testAStarC.m the line 'cellNodes{keyID}.x = cellNodes{keyID}.x;' can be removed without causing the error.

Although unrelated to the crash, the use of memcpy to get scalar doubles has been replaced with mxGetScalar().

Node constructor:

```
Node::Node(mxArray *cellElement)
{
    char strIn[15];
    double tempVal[1];

    size_t numCellElms = mxGetNumberOfFields(cellElement);
    mwSize buflen;

    for (int cellItem = 0; cellItem < numCellElms; cellItem++)
    {
        mxArray *cellElement2 = mxGetCell(cellElement,cellItem);
    
        switch (cellItem)
        {
            case 0:
                gridX = (int)mxGetScalar(cellElement2);
                break;
            case 1:
                gridY = (int)mxGetScalar(cellElement2);
                break;
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 9:
                buflen = mxGetN(cellElement2)*sizeof(mxChar)+1;
                if (buflen <= 1)
                    connections[cellItem-2][0] = '\0';
                else
                {
                    mxGetString(cellElement2, strIn, buflen);
                    memcpy(&connections[cellItem-2][0], strIn, buflen);              
                }
                break;
            case 10:
                posX = mxGetScalar(cellElement2);        
                break;
            case 11:
                posY = mxGetScalar(cellElement2);  
                break;
            case 12:
                wpX = mxGetScalar(cellElement2);
                break;
            case 13:
                wpY = mxGetScalar(cellElement2);    
                break;
            case 14:
                weight = mxGetScalar(cellElement2);
                break;
        }
    }
    
    sprintf(xStr,"%i",gridX);
    sprintf(yStr,"%i",gridY);
    sprintf(key,"%ix%i",gridX,gridY);
}
```

testAStarC.m

```
function waypointsList = getWP(map, initNode, finalNode, targetCoords, heuristic)
    % HashMap containing the nodes (this is a Java hashmap)
    nodesHash = map.navMap.nodes.nodes;
    keys = nodesHash.keys();
    numNodes = length(keys);

    cellNodes = cell(1,numNodes);

    % Parse the nodes from the HashMap to Cells as the MEX seems to be
    % unable to read directly from the Java HashMap
    for keyID=1:numNodes
        cellNodes{keyID} = nodesHash(keys{keyID});
    end

    waypointsList = AStar(cellNodes, initNode, finalNode, targetCoords, heuristic, 1);
```

**2) Is there a more elegant way of forcing Matlab to create a real copy of a variable?**
No, the best you can do is try the assignment trick.